# How can I display test setup and teardown in allure with junit5?

Tags: java, junit5, allure

I am trying to figure out how to work with test setup, body and teardown in the execution summary of an allure report generated from junit5. I am using aspectjweaver as jvm agent as this seams to be necessary to display the execution summary whatsoever.

I figured the junit5 @BeforeEach and @AfterEach methods should be displayed in test setup and teardown. Unfortunately for me they are always displayed inside the test body and setup/teardown do not show up at all.

In following example

```
@BeforeEach
public void before() {
    before_step();
}

@Step("before step")
public void before_step() {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

the allure report will show the method in the test body like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5LjE.png).

Does someone have an idea why this is? Is this just not implemented correctly, do i need to implement something differently or do I maybe have a completely wrong idea as how this should be displayed?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable test fixtures you need to use `allure-junit5` dependency.
Then you can use AllureJunit5 extension on your tests - that will enable fixtures reporting.

The global configuration is also possible. To enable AllureJunit5 extension for all
your tests you need to start your JVM with `-Djunit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled=true` system property.
For more details on automatic extension registration please follow https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic

Comment: Since I'm working with an own java framework instead of using maven or such for test execution, setting the global configuration did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @Dmitry- Can this be done for testng as well?